# How to Get Ajax data in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I tried a custom ajax function in wordpress admin page to get data from ajax method but nothing happened.

How can I solve it?

**code javascript and ajax:**

```
function GetName() {
        var baseurl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
        var geturl = baseurl + '?page=get-name-member-category';

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            url: geturl,
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Backend data PHP response code:**

```
public function getSelectedName()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix .'admin_custom_users';
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM $table WHERE member_category = 'Ordinary-Members'";
        $data =  $wpdb->get_results($sql);
       echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action) how to register and call AJAX actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can send ajax call in wordpress by adding add action hook in your custom theme or plugin . Below I am giving the php and js code

```
<?php
    add_action('wp_ajax_myAjaxFun', 'myAjaxFun');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxFun', 'myAjaxFun');

    function myAjaxFun(){
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix .'admin_custom_users';
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM $table WHERE member_category = 'Ordinary-Members'";
        $data =  $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        echo json_encode($data);
        die();  
    }
?>
```

Your ajax call should be in the below format

```
$.ajax({
    url : baseUrl+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", //baseUrl is wordpress root url 
    type : 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data : {
    action:'myAjaxFun',//this is must
    data1:'test',
    data2:'sample',
    //.....
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: how to get json get data

Comment: @AravinthE In response right? I have console log that response in my js code

Comment: You ajax url  is wrong in the question, You should use the url same as the one I have used in my answer

Comment: @AravinthE  Url path should be `url : baseUrl+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"` It will automatically call the add_action function if action is set as `'myAjaxFun'` in data . I hope this make sense